# Representation Theory over field of characteristic 2

Tags: representation-theory

How can we find a G-invariant form without getting something trivial by the usual averaging process?

Comment: By $G$-invariant form, I'm guessing that you mean an inner product for which the representation is unitary? That is, an analogue of $$[u,v]=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\langle \rho(g)u,\rho(g)v\rangle$$ where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard inner product?

Comment: yes here $\langle,\rangle$ is the standard inner product defined using the frobenius endomorphism.

Comment: Could you explain how the Frobenius endomorphism plays a role here? I don't really see it. Maybe I'm just dense though.

Comment: The conjugate of an element $k$ in a finite field of even prime power $q$ is defined as $k^{\sqrt{q}}$.  From here we have the usual definition of inner product.

Comment: I don't know of any other useful inner product over a finite field that has properties similar to the hermetian inner products over complex vector spaces.

Comment: Oh I get your point now. I didn't realize you were already considering finite fields to begin with. When I took representation theory, my professor would always say "except on a field of characteristic 2 [because it's hard]". I'd love to see an approach for this.

Comment: The normalization constant $\frac{1}{|G|}$ is not needed in front of the summation to form a $G$-invariant form. The issue then becomes that probably not every $G$-invariant form can be made from a sum over "inner products" in this way.

Comment: I think we won't get a trivial invariant form if the order of the group is odd.